# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken Error since re cloned git repo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have locally deleted my Rails GitHub Project and re-cloned it but since then I am getting the error "ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken" when trying to login through Devise. 
[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gu5oV.png)

```
 def handle_unverified_request
      raise ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
    end
  end
end
```

Does it ring a bell for anybody? Maybe some sort of encrypting key have been changed?

I have tried with a different browser, deleting my cookies but same issue.

Thanks

Comment: Problem solved by installing and configuring: ActiveRecord Session Store
https://github.com/rails/activerecord-session_store

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable the dev cache.

Run `rails dev:cache`, then restart the dev server.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out this same issue and this fix works. But I never had to do this before, so why now? And better yet, why?

Comment: The command creates a file in the tmp directory called "caching-dev.txt", that tells rails to use caching in development.

By default that file doesn't exist, and is also included in the default .gitignore file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. TIL something new.